# When executing subquery getting error "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting below error when executing subquery

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Can someone guide me where I am doing wrong. When I tried with Top 1 in the query, I am getting `ElapsedSecond =0` for all the rows.

Here is my query

```
SELECT [Id] 
      ,[LogTime]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Type]
      ,[User]    
      ,ElapsedSecond =
      (SELECT 
     ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, nextStartTime, StartTime), 0)) AS Elapsedsecond
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT  starttime,
            LEAD(StartTime) OVER ( Partition by [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) 
            AS  nextStartTime
        from [dbo].[Log] 
   ) l
   )
  FROM  [dbo].[Log]
```

Expected Output should be

| Id | LogTime | StartTime | Source | Type | User | ElapsedSecond |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | P | I | abc | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | 2021-02-2401:15:46.647 | P | P | abc | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | P | E | abcd | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | H | D | efg | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | C | S | cde | 0 |

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit, sorry I added expected output table.

Comment: Great, now only the input is still missing... Please read my first comment again, *all* of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you don't correlate your sub-query to your outer query to ensure only one value per row. However I think you can accomplish what you want with a derived table sub-query rather than a correlated sub-query. Certainly the following produces the desired results with the data provided.

```
SELECT
    [Id] 
    , [LogTime]
    , [StartTime]
    , [Source]
    , [Type]
    , [User]    
    , ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, nextStartTime, StartTime), 0)) AS Elapsedsecond
FROM (
    SELECT Id, LogTime, StartTime, [Source], [Type], [User]
        , LEAD(StartTime) OVER (Partition by [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) AS nextStartTime
    FROM dbo.[Log] 
) X
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Hi Dale, Thank you! One question, I would like to ask is that If I create a View for this, how to order record because `order by` clause is invalid in View.

Comment: You can't, views need to be ordered by when selected from not within the view.